# Does schema normalization enhances query efficiency

Tags: normalization

I understand the importance of normalization in reducing data redundancy and various anomalies but I am wondering if it can also enhance the performance of your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

If normalization leads you to split your relations into multiple tables, and if you build those tables with primary keys and foreign keys which are defined to the database so that they are properly indexed, then in that sense query performance is enhanced.

Similarly, if your table is not in 1NF you might have to do expensive table scans and text parsing to find examples of a particular data item in a multivalued column.  In 3NF this column could be indexed making the query more efficient.

It's worth noting that normalizing your schema may also make your queries simpler and easier to maintain for the same reasons and in the same situations.

On the other hand, when data has become static (e.g. historical data) it is often denormalized to make retrieval faster.  This frequently takes the form of precalculating values, especially aggregate values.  This is the approach of data warehousing.  It is a good practice, as long as the risk of data insert/update/delete anomalies is very, very low or easy to manage.

Comment: Related: some optimizations (like table elimination) can be used if there are unique/foreign key constraints. Example this question (for Oracle but several DBMS have similar optimizations): http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101051/will-the-oracle-optimizer-still-plan-a-join-if-im-not-reading-any-columns-in-th So, complex queries (coming from views or otherwise) can be sometimes simplified if there are constraints defined. Simpler queries, simpler plans, less table scans/seeks, more efficient.

Comment: I have been doing some digging @Joel Brown and found that the efficiency of a query depends on how well the query is written and that no matter how well your schema is normalized if the query is not well written then is inefficient. For example using a non-indexed attribute in a WHERE clause. Any thought on this?

Comment: @FokwaBest - There is no one factor that has 100% influence over query efficiency.  If your schema doesn't permit an efficient query because it is badly structured, then you obviously won't have one.  Lack of normalization is not the only (or necessarily the most important) way in which your schema could inhibit query efficiency.  Inappropriate indexing is more important, for example.  If your schema isn't an obstacle but you write your query in an inefficient way then of course your query will be inefficient.  What you have, how you structure it and how you access it all come into play.

Comment: I see. Great thought @Joel Brown.